# Expressing vectors in a paralelogram given midpoints

Tags: vectors

Say we have a parallelogram $ABXY$ where $P$ is midpoint to $BX$ and $Q$ is midpoint to $XY$. Can we express vectors $\vec{BX}$ and $\vec{XY}$ in terms of $\vec{AP}$ and $\vec{AQ}$ ??

Answer (score 1):

I think can use $\vec{BX}=\vec{AY},\vec{XY}=-\vec{YX}$ and $$\frac{1}{2}\vec{AY}+\vec{YX}=\vec{AP}$$ $$\vec{AY}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{YX}=\vec{AQ}$$so $$\vec{BX}=\vec{AY}=\frac{2}{3}\left(2\vec{AQ}-\vec{AP}\right)$$$$\vec{XY}=-\vec{YX}=-\frac{2}{3}\left(2\vec{AP}-\vec{AQ}\right)$$ hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a parallelogram, $\vec{AB}=-\vec{XY}$ and $\vec{AY}=\vec{BX}$. Using that $P$ is the midpoint of $BX$:
$$\vec{AP} = \vec{AB} + \vec{BP} = -\vec{XY} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{BX}.$$
Analogously:
$$\vec{AQ} = \vec{AY} + \vec{YQ} = \vec{BX} - \frac{1}{2}\vec{XY}.$$
Now you just need to solve the system.